# drupal didn't send selected value from dropdown list

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

i wanna ask why drupal doesnt send value according to what i'm selected
    [image: Insert]
look at "Pada JP ke ..." i selected "6", and when i submit it

[image: submit]
drupal send "3" instead of "6",
my code here

```
$def = !empty($form_state['values']['jpke']) ? $form_state['values']['jpke'] : 1;
$query1 = db_select('1_jupe', 'jupe')->fields('jupe', array('no'));
$options2 = $query1->execute()->fetchCol(); 
$form['desc1']['jpke'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#default_value' => $def,
  '#title' => t('Pada JP ke ...'),
  '#options' => $options2, // the list only has 4 values (1,2,3,6)
);
```

the insert/submit code

```
$entry = array(  
'jp_ke' => $form_state['values']['jpke'],
'nama_lomba' => $form_state['values']['nama_lomba'],
'kategori' => $form_state['values']['kategori'],  
);
$tabel = '1_jp_lomba';
$return = insert_form($entry,$tabel);
dpm($form_state['values']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you print the full code here so that we can understand it properly.I mean to say that the form in which this form is included and the submit function of the form.
One thing more that can help you .In the form_state values array we will get the key of the selected value from the selectlist.It will doesnot give the values.

Comment: the full code is quite too long to write it here, or do you mean the function instead? and the submit form its already written there

Comment: Are you facing this problem till now.The drupal will return the key of the value that  is selected from select list in the form_state array.You can also send me the file in zipped format.My email id is valecha29@gmail.com.

Comment: I will check the code that you will sent.The formstate array will return the correct values.As I will already told you that it will return the key of the array that is passed to the selectlist as options. For more help you can print the options result that  is fetched from the 1_jupe table.From this you can understand easily.

Comment: If you are not more familiar with the module development then you can use the examples module that will give you the rich knowledge.http://drupal.org/project/examples

Comment: i have read and use the examples modules, but still not work. and the file i send. can u managed to do that?

Comment: I will tell you that there is no issue in the code. You can understand what I mean to say.In the formstate array you will get the key of the  value that is selected from the selectlist.You can print the $options array that is passed as options to the select list.After that you will understand what I'm saying u.